# WCF authentification, and authorization by username/password to restrict services

Tags: wcf, authorization, wcf-security

I want to make wcf authentication, by username and password. After that, to make custom attributes to services, to restrict access by username. For example if authenticated username is User to restrict access to delete, if moderator to allow.
How to do that, and what are the best practices?

Comment: Hi croisharp, you might want to have a look at claims based security http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx. Should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is:

- Custom [user name password validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx) or [membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049.aspx) to authenticate your users
- [Role based security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731200.aspx) or [custom service authorization manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731774.aspx) where you get

You can also thing about [using roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702542.aspx) and assign users to roles outside of your service - it will simplify authorization once you will need multiple users to do the same thing.

Comment: If i want to restrict access to some services, without changing the implementation of service? I mean to make a custom attribute, but is possible to create cookies and check by cookie if user is admin or simple user?

Comment: You need custom service authorization manager which can be assigned from the configuration file.

Comment: Can i know what is the username of authenticated user, that  requires a service?

Comment: Try `operationContext.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name`

Comment: Can i use NetSqlAzMan as an authorization manager, and membership provider?